# Graphql typescript typing and codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

The library called [apollo-codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-codegen) allows one to create types on the client for a graphQL schema. However it expect the `gql` queries to be put in a `.graphql` file.

My question is: how can I use the query when they are in a `.graphql` file ?

I was previously doing this in my `.ts` files

```
const ssQuery = gql`
    subscription suppliers {
        suppliers {
            id,
            name
        }
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using webpack, [graphql-tag](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag) includes a loader to import the queries.

```
// webpack.config.js

loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader'
  }
]

// in your project
import MY_QUERY from './my-query.graphql'

graphql(MY_QUERY)(MyComponent)
```

Be mindful that doing this means you should have only one query/mutation/subscription per file. However, you can also create files for fragments and import them inside the graphql file (not sure if apollo-codegen supports this syntax though).

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate, I'm using angular-cli and the webpack config is not available.

Comment: FWIW, this might be of help: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/issues/321